# How can i compare two dates (NSDate) in Swift 3 and get the days between them?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, nsdate, date-comparison

How can I compare two dates in Swift 3?
I found many solutions for other Swift versions, but they doesn't work for me.

```
let clickedDay:String = currentcell.DayLabel.text!
    let currentDate = NSDate()
    let currentDay = "" //want the current day
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()        
    var dateAsString = ""        
    if Int(clickedDay)! < 10 {            
        dateAsString = "0" + clickedDay + "-11-2016 GMT"
    }
    else {            
        dateAsString = clickedDay + "-11-2016 GMT"
    }

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy zzz"
    let clickedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString)        
    if currentDate as Date >= clickedDate! as Date {

        return true
    }
    else {
        //Want to get the days between the currentDate and clickedDate
        let daysLeft = ""
    }
```

I compare the tow dates, but i want the days which are between that tow dates.
Can someone help me pls?
Thanks and greets

Added:
If I have the date 22.11.2016 and the currentdate (now 18.11.2016) i want the days between that (in this case 4)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply make extension of `Date` like this and get difference in days.

```
extension Date {
    func daysBetweenDate(toDate: Date) -> Int {
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: toDate)
        return components.day ?? 0
    }
}
```

Now use this extension like this

```
let numOfDays = fromDate.daysBetweenDate(toDate: toDate)
```

You can use `DateFormatter` to convert String to Date like this.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "18-11-2016")
```

Comment: Where i declaire the extension?

Comment: Get this error: use of unresolved identifier 'fromDate'

Comment: That works, but if i have the 18.11.2016 (fromdate) and 22.11.2016 (todate), it says 3 days

Comment: How i give them the right timezone? like this: dateAsString = clickedDay + "-11-2016 GMT" ??

Comment: @Mbach Check the edited answer to convert string to date, there is no need to add "GMT" with your dateString.

Comment: @Mbach I'm talking about this `"0" + clickedDay + "-11-2016 GMT"`

Comment: @Mbach Welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Try This One

```
let startDateComparisionResult:ComparisonResult = currentDate.compare(clickedDate! as NSDate)

if startDateComparisionResult == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
{
    // Current date is smaller than end date.
}
else if startDateComparisionResult == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
{
    // Current date is greater than end date.
}
else if startDateComparisionResult == ComparisonResult.orderedSame
{
    // Current date and end date are same
}
```

Comment: Depends on your currentDate and clickedDate value

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
let days=Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date_1, to: date_2)
let nb_days=days.day
```

Comment: I want the days, how long it is to the next date

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you well. My answer gives you the number of days between your_date and Date() (so today). But if you want to compare with another date just change Date() with next_date.

Comment: Yes thats what i want. but in days I have no number, how get I the number?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the second part :) I updated my answer @Mbach

Answer (score 2):

Use this function to get all intermediate dates between two dates, just check if down date (final date) is greater than up date (first date) then order is +1, else order -1 :-

```
func selectDates(from upDate : Date, to downDate : Date, order : Int){
        var selectDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: order, to: upDate)!
        while compareDate(dateInitial: selectDate, dateFinal: downDate) != true{
            print(" intermediate date is \(selectDate)")
            selectDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: order, to: selectDate)!
        }
        print("*** intermediate dates are selected ***")

    }


func compareDate(dateInitial:Date, dateFinal:Date) -> Bool {
        let order = Calendar.current.compare(dateInitial, to: dateFinal, toGranularity: .day)
        switch order {
        case .orderedSame:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want the days, how long it is to the next date